# Node.JS Lambda Function Not Returning JSON

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm new to NodeJS, and JS in general (mostly a PHP and C# guy), so I could really use some help with this function below.

The goal is to receive a JSON payload, connect to MySQL, and then return the results of the query in a JSON response. I've got it connecting to the DB, I can read the JSON data that it receives (event.fieldname) but for some reason it's not sending back the JSON for the applicant_data variable.

Do I just have the variable in the wrong location? When I run the code below I just get back "{}" as the returned data.

Thanks in advance for the help!

NodeJS Code:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
console.log('Starting:');
console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));

var mysql = require('mysql');



var jsonconnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'servername',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database'
 });

jsonconnection.connect();
console.log('Connected to MySQL:');

jsonconnection.query('SELECT applicant_id FROM customers WHERE applicant_id = \'' + event.applicant_id + '\'',
    function(err,res){
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log('Row Details:', JSON.stringify(res));
        var applicant_data = {
            applicant_id : res.applicant_id
        };

    jsonconnection.end();

    context.succeed(applicant_data);
 })
};
```

Comment: How are you invoking the Lambda function? Via API gateway? Or directly via the AWS SDK?

Comment: Please add the output of line `console.log('Row Details:', JSON.stringify(res));`

Comment: Invoking via the API Gateway.

Comment: Results from `console.log('Row Details:')`

Row Details: [{"applicant_id":"WQFV7CWXA39E9TXT"}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with AWS, but base on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html, following code may work.

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    console.log('Starting:');
    console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));

    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var jsonconnection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'servername',
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'database'
    });

    // Move applicant_data outside of query as it will be needed at the end in callback
    var applicant_data = {};

    jsonconnection.connect();
    console.log('Connected to MySQL:');

    jsonconnection.query('SELECT applicant_id FROM customers WHERE applicant_id = \'' + event.applicant_id + '\'',
        function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log('Row Details:', JSON.stringify(res));
            applicant_data = {
                // Only use first row of data
                applicant_id: res[0].applicant_id;
            };

        });

    // Move connection end out side of query
    jsonconnection.end();

    // This should return your data, in JSON form
    callback(null, JSON.stringify(applicant_data));

    // I assume this is the correct use for succeed
    context.succeed();
};
```

Comment: Hi @john-siu, 

Unfortunately that doesn't work as expected... I tried that earlier :-)  

What it sends back is the following with the brackets before and after... not exactly JSON :-(

[
         {
        "applicant_id":"WQFV7CWXA39E9TXT"
      }
]

Comment: If I return the applicant_data JSON variable outside of the callback function it returns the data as I would expect without the brackets.

Comment: @Josh It is JSON, but wrapped in an array. The data is in first item of the array.

Comment: @Josh Try without JSON.stringify in callback, it is not required. I updated my answer. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback

Comment: Thanks for the assist here... I tried it without the stringify and I'm still getting just a { }  :-(

Comment: @Josh Discovered a logical bug. query response is a row array, have to use index[0] to extract the data.

Comment: THAT DID THE TRICK! Thanks so much John... really appreciate the help. My final solution to get rid of the array notation before the JSON was to use my original context.succeed(applicant_data) so I'm getting back just a single JSON and I'm good to go! Accepting your answer and thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let jsonResponse = {"hello":"world"}
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(jsonResponse),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to return the JSON data as an object instead of a string?

Comment: @Crashalot this would be interpreted as an object by most clients and servers.